# Is there a way to use docker manifest-list to build multi-arch images in ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, multiarch

I am trying to use Amazon ECR for storing my images.

Now, I want my image:tag to work with different operating system and architectures like linux/amd64, linux/arm64, windows etc.

This is fine when I use docker but seems like I can't make it work with ECR.

Docker says you can push it to an insecure registry:
  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest/

**Failed command:**

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t 5XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:tag --push .
```

**This command succeeds:**

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t 5XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:tag --push .
```

The multi-platform image can be pushed to Docker Hub.

---

I want to know a way how we can do this. This is my thought. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Can we create our own manifest file which contains the images already placed in ECR repository?

Something like:

```
image: image:multi-arch
manifests:
   -
      image: 5XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:tag/i1-linuxamd64
      platform:
             architecture: arm64
      os: linux

   -
      image: 5XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/imagename:tag/i2-intelx86
      platform:
             architecture: intelx86
      os: Windows
```

Now we have a new image called **image:multi-arch**. We then use this image and expect it to get the target architecture automatically based on the manifest.

If I push this final image to ECR, will it work?
Am I doing something wrong? Please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECR does not currently support multi-architecture images.  You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/505) on the AWS Containers Roadmap for updates.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel. I just wanted to know if there is a workaround or so. But seems like there isn't. :)

Comment: where is thee issue link?

Comment: @Adiii Oops, fixed!

Answer (score 5):

**Pushing a multi-architecture image: Now Available**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-multi-architecture-image.html